# Can I use logistic regressions and least squares coefficients in a meta-analysis?

Tags: logistic, least-squares, meta-analysis, meta-regression, economics

I am trying to write a Economics meta-analysis. The papers that I have collected so far contain a 50/50 split between OLS models and Logistic regressions (coefficients reported as odds ratios). If we assume for simplicity that all the outcome variables are measured in the same way, I have used the method described [here](https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_9/9_4_6_combining_dichotomous_and_continuous_outcomes.htm) to convert the odds ratios to SMDs.

My plan is to estimate the model using both the OLS and Logistic coefficients. I will include dummy variables for the different model types, as a form of subgroup analysis. Is this okay to do?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Seems reasonable. Do you have some specific doubt?

Comment: I'm getting some strangely low transformed coefficients and high standard errors. Also i've read a few papers online that highlight problems with using models that contain different numbers of covariates. Do you know how this is usually dealt with?

Comment: If the other covariates differ then the coefficients will not be strictly comparable between studies even using just OLS or just logistic.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you reported is correct, even if it requires an assumption (logistic distribution of the underlying model).

The different set of covariates, however, not only changes the interpretation (you get different conditional associations depending on the different set of covariates you control for) in case of omitted covariates (if you assumed that, when a covariate is omitted in a given model, it is because its "real" value is 0, then you wouldn't have such bias).
In fact, it generates an issue with binary outcomes, since the $OR$ you get changes its interpretation. This is because, due to noncollapsibility, even controlling for a variable that is not a confounder (since it's not associated with the predictor) changes the parameter value of interest. This is because the marginal $OR$ (i.e., the $OR$ on the population) is different from the conditional $OR$ (i.e., the $OR$ at the individual level).

Thus, depending on the set of covariates, your $OR$ should be interpreted differently (becoming the $OR$ on subgroups defined by equality of all the predictors in the model), even if such covariates are not confounders.